# How to add custom titles wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, themes, title

I am trying to add some custom titles in my page http://www.delpapafamily.com/new/#!/del-papa-family-farm/.

I can print the page title in page.php using the code

```
<?php echo "Name=".$post->post_name; ?>
```

But when I put the same code in header, I am not able to get the page title.

Please take a look at http://www.delpapafamily.com/new/#!/del-papa-family-farm/. Now this page prints the tiles from both header.php and page.php codes. But it does not show the page title from the header.php code.

It is really urgent .

Sincerely,

Sunil

Comment: any body to help ...................

Answer (score 0):

The loop may not yet be initialized in your header. Try using `wp_title()` instead. The codex reference is [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title).